# Specify only YEAR and MONTH for input date min/max attributes

Tags: javascript, html, input

i have the following:

```
<input type="date" max="2014-10-31">
```

Can i specify only the **year** and the **month**? I guess it'd be like:

```
<input type="date" max="2014-10-xx">
```

or just

```
<input type="date" max="2014-10">
```

(assuming the format is yyyy/mm/dd).

And HTML does the rest. I can't specific the day, only year and month (given by server-side), because there are different max days for each month (like february, which has 28). So, can not be 31 the max.

*when i put **31** [day] for max attribute, the months that have 28, 30 stop working, i mean, the `input` gets weird and so i can modify the month too, but it can't happen cause the user should be able only to change the **day** - the month and the days are specific.*

Comment: I don't know but why don't you take the first day or calculate the last day of the month?

Comment: Yeah. I was thinking about it. But so i started wondering whether there's not an easier solution.

Comment: It isn't that hard to get the last day of the month though, because I don't think you can use your prefered examples or you'll have to use a library for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```html
<input class="month-date" type="date" max="2014-02">
```

```js
var els = document.getElementsByClassName("month-date");
for(var i=0, l=els.length; i<l; ++i) {
    var max = els[i].getAttribute('max').split('-');
    max.push(new Date(max[0], max[1], 0).getDate());
    els[i].max = max.join('-');
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9n66W/)

Comment: It allows the user to change the month and the year, yet.

Comment: @kratos On which browser? I can't select any date after February 2014 on Chromium 36.

Comment: Nevermind. My fault, i forgot the `min`. Thank you. You're awesome. :)

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that with HTML. The `max` value in in [`<input type="date" ...>`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#date-state-%28type=date%29) must by definition be a specific date, and it must be a valid date.

You should calculate the last day of the intended month when you generate the HTML markup.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use like following:

```
Date(day/month/year): <input type="date" value="2017-07-20" min="2000-01-01" max="2020-01-01">
<hr />
Date(Month/Year): <input type="month" value="2017-07" min="2000-01" max="2020-01">
<hr />
Date(year): <input type="number" value="2017" min="2000" max="2020">
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/2fupfqgz/2/